# How to achieve end-end debugging in visual studio using projects that reference sub-projects via (custom) nuget packages

Tags: git, debugging, nuget, git-submodules, projects-and-solutions

We have a solution A, which is a desktop application, which contains various projects.

Solution A uses code from Projects X,Y,Z, which used to live inside solution A but have been isolated into separate repositories, and uploaded to a custom nuget feed on devops.

I would like to be able to debug solution A, and change code from X,Y,Z all in the same place, instead of needing to push changes to X,Y,Z seperately and pull the nuget artifact created in devops back into solution A. Git submodules seems promising, but I have been unable to get visual studio to play nice, and i'm not sure whether I can use it in tandem with nuget packages.

Is there a simple answer to this problem?